# AX 2012 ODBC Connection Without Active Directory user

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am having problem trying to connect to an external database with Microsoft Dynamics AX.

I have configured the dsn, and i can connect with sql server authentication (not active directory, because is in another server), and when i test, it just works.

But when i try to use the dsn in x++ i am sending the correct user and password to the loginProperty, but always return error, it try to do with the active directory user.

This is my code:

```
LoginProperty                   loginProperty;
OdbcConnection                  odbcConnection;
Statement                       statement;
ResultSet                       resultSet;
str                             sql, criteria;
SqlStatementExecutePermission   perm;
TLExternalUser                  tlExternaUser;
TLExternalUserPwd               tlExternalUserPwd;
str                             strConnectionString;
str                             dsn         = "myDsnName";
str                             dsnUser     = "sqlUser";
str                             dsnUSerPwd  = "sqlPWD";

strConnectionString = strfmt("UID=%1;PWD=%2",dsnUser,dsnUSerPwd);
loginProperty = new LoginProperty();
loginProperty.setDSN(dsn);
loginProperty.setDatabase("MyDatabase");
loginProperty.setOther(strConnectionString);
   odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(loginProperty);

if (odbcConnection)
{
    info("success");
}
else
{
    throw error("Failed to log on to the database through ODBC.");
}
```

But i am getting this error:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\ACTIVEDIRECTORYUSER'.
```

I was looging to pass directly to my loginProperty the username and password, but such methods does not exist.

How can i make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not make it works with dsn, so i use server, in this way:

```
LoginProperty                   loginProperty;
OdbcConnection                  odbcConnection;
Statement                       statement;
ResultSet                       resultSet;
str                             sql ;
SqlStatementExecutePermission   perm;
TLExternalUser                  tlExternaUser;
TLExternalUserPwd               tlExternalUserPwd;
str                             strConnectionString;
str                             dbServer    = 'myipServer';
str                             serverDbUser     = 'myUser';
str                             serverDbUserPwd  = 'MyPassword';

strConnectionString = strfmt("UID=%1;PWD=%2",serverDbUser,serverDbUserPwd);

loginProperty = new LoginProperty();

loginProperty.setServer(dbServer);
loginProperty.setDatabase("MyDatabase");
loginProperty.setOther(strConnectionString);

odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(loginProperty);
```

I do not understand why with dsn does not work

Comment: You didn't change the connection string like I suggested. `"DSN=%1;UID=%2;PWD=%3",dsn, dsnUser,dsnUSerPwd`. It worked in my test?  Are you setting the DSN correctly?

Comment: well, i try as you suggested, and same problem, using dsn dit not work, i was setting the dsn correctly of course, but it always try to connect with active directory credentials, and not custom user. With server it works, i am not using extrange chars in my password, for that i dont include, but i will consider to include later

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to this and removing `loginProperty.setDSN(...)`:

```
strConnectionString = strfmt("DSN=%1;UID=%2;PWD=%3",dsn, dsnUser,dsnUSerPwd);
loginProperty = new LoginProperty();
loginProperty.setDatabase("MyDatabase");
loginProperty.setOther(strConnectionString);
```

**Edit** If your password has special characters in it, you will need to either escape them with a backslash `\` or place an `@` symbol before the quotes to indicate a string literal, like this `str myPass = @'MyP@ssw0rd';`.

See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa889472.aspx

Comment: Are you positive the user/pass is correct? Do you have any special characters that need escaped in the string?  Try placing the password like `@'MyPassword'`. See my answer edit.

Comment: i am sure that im sending the right credentials. i try to pass my password in that way, doesnt work